# X3d file from s3 bucket not loading

Tags: javascript, html, angular, amazon-s3, x3d

i have to load x3d file from s3 bucket. this is how i implemented inline tag with in scene tag but it not working. need suggestions and help

```
<scene><inline [attr.url]='"https://<xyz>.s3.amazonaws.com/cca40389-e252-4601-b971-1d2c2d8872a7/basic-shapes.x3d?X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-Algorithm=..."'></inline>
</scene>
```

Comment: This is a request for more information; can you view the results of loading this file in the network console of one of the browsers.  The question is whether requesting the s3 link is denied because of a CORS violation. If so, then this would be a Amazon Web Services question more than X3D question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.